# Passing JWT token to access API

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, token, access-token

I am trying to display image by API call. My API works well in POSTMAN. I am using JWT token for session maintaining. I don't know where to pass the token in browser url.

**Images**

[API working in POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/holne.jpg)

[I don't how to pass token in browser URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayHKW.png)

Comment: can u give the server side code?

Comment: You don't pass tokens in *browser urls*. What are trying to do? Call the API from within the browser? It's not intended for such use.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass tokens in browser URLs. Authorization tokens are mostly used in request header. For that you need to add the corresponding header on each request. So you have two options:

1. [Add authorization token on each request individually](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/),
2. [Add a HttpInterceptor.](https://medium.com/@milosbejda/adding-authorization-header-to-http-request-in-angular-4-and-5-777b2ce05424)

Hope it helps.